# Eclipse doesn't generate parent theme files in Liferay maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, liferay

I'm trying to create new theme plugin in Liferay 6.2.1 in Eclipse with maven. When I followed the official tutorial it creates project with almost empty WEB-INF - no _diffs folder, css, images and others. What do I do wrong?

[image: My project structure]
[image: How i create theme plugin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_diffs folder is probably used only for Ant builds. In maven project you simply create css folder and others under /webapp.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official answer from the Liferay documentation:

> The src/main/webapp/ folder holds your theme’s customizations. This folder is used the same way that the docroot/_diffs/ folder is used in themes developed via the Liferay Plugins SDK. If you’re using the Plugins SDK, any of your theme’s files that differ from the corresponding files of your theme’s base theme go in the docroot/_diffs/ folder. If you’re using Maven, any of your theme’s files that differ from the corresponding files of your theme’s base theme go in the src/main/webapp/ folder. For example, if you’ve modified css/custom.css in your theme, your custom.css file should go in the src/main/webapp/css/ folder.

Found here: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/developing-liferay-theme-plugins-with-maven